# How can I manage height and width of images coming from Google app engine in list view?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am developing an android application using Google app engine.We have custom list view in which image has to be shown. I have used lazy loading for list view to load more data on demand.But problem is here, I am getting images from server, User can upload images of any size. Being used such images by user, I am not able to manage height and width for every image in list view List view is looking very ugly. How can I manage such images in specific height and width in image view?

Please share your best answer.

Thanks,
Prashant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Images API for this. It has the capability to resize images have a look at

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/

Using this you can

- **Resize**
- **Rotate**
- **Flip horizontally**
- **Flip vertically**
- **Crop**

any image at runtime

Now when fetching the images use resize to scale down images to a specific dimension and use it in your  listview

Answer (score 0):

Simply there are 2 options.

1. Use android's ImageView.ScaleType

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

```
ImageView iv = someView;
iv.setScaleType(CENTER_CROP) // also CENTER_INSIDE, CENTER, whatever you want.
```

or in xml

```
<ImageView
  ...
  android:scaleType="center" />
```

2. use blobstore magic url

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_get_serving_url